# How to inform user that the interactive notification action has failed or no longer available

Tags: ios, ios8, notifications, uilocalnotification

I have an app that uses the iOS 8 interactive notifications, as I enable the user to check-in from the lock screen

The problem is that the app logic should prevent the user from checking in after one minute from the notification time. I already check the time before executing the logic but I don't know how to inform the user that the operation was failed as the `(void (^)())completionHandler` does not take any argument.

As result the user sees that the action is done and the notification is disappeared which indicate that every thing went Ok

So there is any way to tell the user that the action is no longer available, or inform him that the action was not done successfully